Cannot Find Solution to this React Native Expo Gradle Error

Task :app:compileReleaseKotlin FAILED
e: file:///C:/Users/Saad/Storeapp/android/app/src/main/java/com/sio/Storeapp/MainActivity.kt:2:25 Unresolved reference: R
e: file:///C:/Users/Saad/Storeapp/android/app/src/main/java/com/sio/Storeapp/MainActivity.kt:3:25 Unresolved reference: BuildConfig
e: file:///C:/Users/Saad/Storeapp/android/app/src/main/java/com/sio/Storeapp/MainActivity.kt:20:14 Unresolved reference: R
e: file:///C:/Users/Saad/Storeapp/android/app/src/main/java/com/sio/Storeapp/MainActivity.kt:37:11 Unresolved reference: BuildConfig
e: file:///C:/Users/Saad/Storeapp/android/app/src/main/java/com/sio/Storeapp/MainApplication.kt:2:25 Unresolved reference: R
e: file:///C:/Users/Saad/Storeapp/android/app/src/main/java/com/sio/Storeapp/MainApplication.kt:3:25 Unresolved reference: BuildConfig
e: file:///C:/Users/Saad/Storeapp/android/app/src/main/java/com/sio/Storeapp/MainApplication.kt:32:60 Unresolved reference: BuildConfig
e: file:///C:/Users/Saad/Storeapp/android/app/src/main/java/com/sio/Storeapp/MainApplication.kt:34:52 Unresolved reference: BuildConfig
e: file:///C:/Users/Saad/Storeapp/android/app/src/main/java/com/sio/Storeapp/MainApplication.kt:35:51 Unresolved reference: BuildConfig
e: file:///C:/Users/Saad/Storeapp/android/app/src/main/java/com/sio/Storeapp/MainApplication.kt:45:9 Unresolved reference: BuildConfig

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileReleaseKotlin'.


A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
Compilation error. See log for more details


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
BUILD FAILED in 3m 25s
354 actionable tasks: 349 executed, 5 up-to-date
Dont Know the solution to this error
